# How do I send a DELETE keystroke to a text field using Selenium with Python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How do I send a Keys.DELETE keystroke to a text field with the Selenium web tester? I'm trying to simulate the user typing in a field and then deleting what they typed to test the interactive autosuggestion feature.  It should filter the list to items beginning with their query, then show all the possible suggestions again when they delete their query.  Unfortunatley sending a .clear() doesn't work to un-filter the list again.  Neither does send_keys('\127').

```
def get_suggestions():
    driver.get('https://www.example.com/')
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#searchQuery').click()
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#searchQuery').send_keys('a')
    sleep(0.5)
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#searchQuery').send_keys(Keys.DELETE)
    sleep(0.5)
    for suggestion in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('#search-form #suggestions'):
        yield suggestion
```

How can I simulate the user pressing the delete button on their keyboard?

Comment: `from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys` just for anyone else wondering how to import it.

Comment: @jmunsch added as an answer. I missed this comment.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need to use `Keys.BACKSPACE` instead of `Keys.DELETE` if you want to delete a character before the cursor. `Keys.DELETE` is used to delete a character after the cursor.

Be sure you are using the following import:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
```

Comment: Yup, ironically I just found the answer after posting this by seeing Keys.BACKSPACE in the autosuggestion list in iPython when I typed Keys.  Feeling kind of dumb right now.

Comment: @NickSweeting, Maybe you're using a Mac? The keyboard layout in the Mac make it confusing ;)

Answer (score 21):

You can use `Ctr+a` to highlight the text and remove it by  `BACKSPACE`:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

element.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, 'a')
element.send_keys(Keys.BACKSPACE)
```

Answer (score 8):

In python if element.clear() (doesn't fire onChange in react) doesn't work try this.

```
def clear_text(element):
            length = len(element.get_attribute('value'))
            element.send_keys(length * Keys.BACKSPACE)
```

Answer (score 6):

Why did no one say the import required?

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
```

Answer (score 5):

Also, if you want to delete the entire text you can mimic the `ctrl + a` & `backspace` in a single function like below:

```
def clear_entire_text(element):
    element.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 'a', Keys.BACKSPACE)
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to simulate the user typing in a field and then deleting
>   what they typed

If you are trying to delete **one key at a time**, then, as @falsetru mentions, using the following will delete one character at a time:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#searchQuery')
element.send_keys(Keys.BACKSPACE)
```

However, if you want to delete **the entire search query**, I would rather clear the input field.

```
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#searchQuery')
element.click()
element.clear()
```

Answer (score 0):

**How to delete a line of text**

This shortcut did not work for me `Ctrl + a`
But `SHIFT + END` worked perfectly

If the cursor is at the end of the line use `SHIFT + HOME`

```
action = ActionChains(driver)
action.key_down(Keys.SHIFT).send_keys(Keys.HOME, Keys.BACKSPACE).perform()
```

If the cursor is at the start of the line use `SHIFT + END`

```
action = ActionChains(driver)
action.key_down(Keys.SHIFT).send_keys(Keys.END, Keys.BACKSPACE).perform()
```