# Input date using Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to input date on a web page using selenium. I've used the code as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://www.nccpl.com.pk/en/market-information/fipi-lipi/lipi-sector-wise-daily') 

datefield = driver.find_element_by_id('popupDatepicker')
datefield = driver.find_element_by_name('value')
datefield.click()
datefield.send_keys("01/01/2019")
```

I am unable to plug in the desired date `"01/01/2019"`. I searched for similar solutions and found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39520708/using-selenium-on-calendar-date-picker).

As suggested in the above mentioned solution I tried using `ActionChains` to perform one task after another but still I was unable to change the date. The piece of code used to perform ActionChains is as follows:

```
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(datefield).click().send_keys('01/01/2019').perform()
```

Any idea if I am doing something wrong or how can I get it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input field `#popupDatepicker` has attribute `readonly`. That means that you cannot send keys to it.

Try below to select required date

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium import webdriver


driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://www.nccpl.com.pk/en/market-information/fipi-lipi/lipi-sector-wise-daily') 
picker = wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'popupDatepicker')))
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView();', picker)
picker.click()
wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[title="Select Tuesday, Jan 1, 2019"]'))).click()
```

If you need to select month or year you need to handle `select` drop-down:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select 

select_month = Select(wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[title="Change the month"]'))))
select_month.select_by_visible_text('April')
select_year = Select(wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[title="Change the year"]'))))
select_year.select_by_visible_text('2018')
```

Comment: I am getting this error now `selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:` even though there is wait time.

Comment: @FurqanHashim , on which line?

Comment: @FurqanHashim , no I mean show me that line. I don't know what is 17th line

Comment: It is this line: `wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'popupDatepicker'))).click()`. Moreover, I think since the page is not scrolled down therefore this line fails clicking the date pop up. If I manually scroll when the page pops up the code works perfectly fine.

Comment: Still same error at this line `picker = wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'popupDatepicker')))`

Comment: @FurqanHashim , Hm... Try to replace `element_to_be_clickable` with `presence_of_element_located`